# Foundation bug in stringByAppendingPathComponent?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, url, foundation

I tried the following line in an iOS app and in a Foundation tool:

```
[@"http://www.apple.com/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"]
```

Every time the result I get is:

```
@"http:/www.apple.com"
```

In other words, `stringByAppendingPathComponent`, in addition to not appending anything (which I expected), swallows the last `/` (which could be considered OK, sort of), ***and*** swallows one of the URL scheme `/`, which is totally *not* OK in my book.

Is this happening only to me? Did I miss something stupid before I file a bug report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note the documentation for `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`:

> Note that this method only works with file paths (not, for example, string representations of URLs).

So you are using the method for a case it is not meant to support.

Using it with a file path shows the same behavior, though:

```
[@"/abc/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"];     // -> @"/abc"
[@"/abc/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/def/"]; // -> @"/abc/def"
```

So the method seems to always prefer paths that do not end with a trailing slash, no matter if the slash was part of the original path or the argument. I don't know if I'd call that a bug, though. After all, both `/abc` and `/abc/` specify the same item on a file system, don't they?

But it sure sounds like the exact behavior could be documented better.

Comment: arf, I hadn't seen the note in the documentation. OK Not a bug. my bad. Thanks.

Comment: This fails too: `[[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"]`. It returns `http://www.apple.com///`. `URLWithString:relativeToURL:` seems to work OK though.